# On Azure AD can the x509 Certificate Subject be returned in the JWT claim

Tags: c#, azure, active-directory, certificate

I am using an x509 certificate to login to Azure AD with a Root certificate. It is returning the JWT correctly and I am using that to access APIM and back ground server.

I would like the Subject of the Certificate to be included in the `upn` field but can not see a clear example anywhere so I could use the Claims Mapping function but cant see an example. As a par tof this I can see in the AD App manifest the value is being mapped to `keyCredentials` \ `displayName` behind the scenes.

I can also access the Subject when passing through the ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder code. Could I add the Subject here as a claim?

```
    X509Certificate2 certificate = X509Certificate2Helper.LoadX509CertificateFromCertificateManager(config);
    IConfidentialClientApplication app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(config.ClientId)
        .WithCertificate(certificate)
        .WithAuthority(new Uri(config.Authority))                  
        .Build();

    string[] resourceIds = new string[] { config.ResourceID };
    AuthenticationResult result = null;
    result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(resourceIds).ExecuteAsync();
```

Thank you

Comment: Here is the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims) on what optional claims that an azure ad can issue as claims in token. Currently issuing certificate's subject name as claim vaule is not supported.

Comment: Do you know if I could set the ```upn``` as it says "Although this claim is automatically included, you can specify it as an optional claim to attach additional properties to modify its behavior in the guest user case."? 

I did see some information about custom mapping but did not see anything about taking from a certificate into the JWT.

Comment: yes , you cannot retrieve certificate used for authentication for optional claims.